# calculating angle between three points but only anticlockwise in python

Tags: python, math, angle

So I'm trying to calculate the angle between three points. for example

```
a = [14, 140]
b = [13, 120]
c = [12, 130]
d = [11, 110]

|
|    c    a
|
|  d    b
|____________
```

say i want to calculate the angle between ABC i use the follow code

```
#create vectors
ba = a - b
bc = c- b
# calculate angle
cosine_angle = numpy.dot(ba,bc) / (numpy.linalg.norm(ba) * numpy.linalg.norm(bc))

angle = numpy.arccos(cosine_angle) 
pAngle = numpy.degrees(angle)
```

My script runs and the output angle works, my issue though is when i want to calculate BCD I want the angle on the outside not the inside so say instead of the angle being 120 degrees i want the angle 240. So i only want the anti-clockwise angles.

Not sure how to get this value, can anyone point me in the right direction?

*edit: in other terms i want to identify angles that are over 180 degrees anticlockwise

*edit2: the duplicate answer does not answer the question for me as i have not used alot of java so not sure how to code that in python

Comment: If you picture any two-line angle, you can always measure a kind of "interior" small angle, an "exterior" larger angle or - in the case of a straight line - two equal angles. Do you always want to return the smaller angle? Or are you actually looking to do this "clockwise" vs "anticlockwise"? I don't have numpy installed, but I wonder if you could effect this by passing your arguments in a different order?

Comment: yeah only anticlockwise, or in other terms i want to identify any angles that are greater than 180 degrees in the anticlockwise direction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Computer Graphics: Rotating a polygon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352311/computer-graphics-rotating-a-polygon)

Comment: The correct way is to use the atan2 function, as described in the duplicate answer. Replace a -> ba and b -> bc to directly apply the formula.

Comment: cold you explain further?

Comment: not sure how to code your solution think i've confused myself to the maximum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now using **angular cosine distance** to calculate the angle between two vectors is quite good, but in your case it might be better to use **arc tangent** as mentioned in the comments.

Now assuming you want to calculate the counterclockwise angle between BCD, you can do this by using the numpy's [atan2](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) function. **atan2(x, y)** will give the angle between the origin point **y** to **x**.

```
import numpy as np

def calculate_angle(point_a, point_b):
    """ Calculate angle between two points """
    ang_a = np.arctan2(*point_a[::-1])
    ang_b = np.arctan2(*point_b[::-1])
    return np.rad2deg((ang_a - ang_b) % (2 * np.pi))

a = np.array([14, 140])
b = np.array([13, 120])
c = np.array([12, 130])
d = np.array([11, 110])

# create vectors
ba = a - b
bc = c - b
cd = d - c

# calculate angle
cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))

angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
inner_angle = np.degrees(angle)

print inner_angle  # 8.57299836361


# see how changing the direction changes the angle
print calculate_angle(bc, cd) # 188.572998364
print calculate_angle(cd, bc) # 171.427001636
```

Comment: You will need to observe that the call is `atan2(y,x)`, probably to be compatible with `atan(y/x)`. Your computation of the separate angles may lead to strange jumps in the angle difference.

Comment: how do you mean lutzl? what would your solution be?

Comment: i noticed when i tried to implement i got a different angle? to previously

Comment: oh i understand now, by changing direction changes the value

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Comment: one last question haha, if i wanted to change to clockwise angle instead of anticlockwise how would i get that value? thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You are able to calculate the inner angle, but you want the reversed angle? why not just calculating `360 - angle`

Comment: Thought about that but then it would cause the ABC angle to be outside as well but that angle is anticlockwise which is fine, I have a dataset if about 20000 points so can't do each point one by one has to run in a loop